# MySQL select 1 row from multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Please Suggest to get single 0 type row from multiple (0 type rows) and selected row should be just before type 1 row

```
Emp_tbl (id,type,company_id,created_at)

1,0,121,2015-02-19 18:05
2,0,121,2015-02-19 18:15
3,0,121,2015-02-19 18:17
4,1,121,2015-02-19 19:22
5,2,121,2015-02-19 19:25

6,0,121,2015-02-19 22:05
7,0,121,2015-02-19 22:15
8,0,121,2015-02-19 22:17
9,1,121,2015-02-19 22:22
10,2,121,2015-02-19 22:25
```

Expected Result

```
3,0,121,2015-02-19 18:17
4,1,121,2015-02-19 19:22
5,2,121,2015-02-19 19:25


8,0,121,2015-02-19 22:17
9,1,121,2015-02-19 22:22
10,2,121,2015-02-19 22:25
```

Comment: it is not clear how the result is produced. Please explain better

Comment: In Actual data,5 rows are present out of which 3 - 0 type ,1 - 1 Type, 2 -2 Type.M looking for 1 row only having 0 type and it should be just before type1 row....

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is the `MAX(Id)` of the `type = 0` rows for each row that has `type = 1`, where the `Id` is less. You can join and group to get that:

```
select max(t0.Id) Id
from Emp_tbl t1
join Emp_tbl t0 on t0.type = 0 and t0.Id < t1.Id
where t1.type = 1
group by t1.Id
```

The rest is just putting it together:

```
select *
from Emp_tbl
where type <> 0
union all
select t.*
from Emp_tbl t
join (
    select max(t0.Id) Id
    from Emp_tbl t1
    join Emp_tbl t0 on t0.type = 0 and t0.Id < t1.Id
    where t1.type = 1
    group by t1.Id
) t0 on t.Id = t0.Id
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48b6f/2)